# Ошибка при подключении к очереди

Tags: php, очередь

Пытаюсь подключиться к очереди (скрипт на одном севере, очередь на другом)
Использую метод AMQPConnection из библиотеки AMQP, кроме 1 строчки ничего другого не выполняется

Пример:

`$connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost',5672,'guest','guest');`

Получаю следующую ошибку: Unable to create SASL Server:AMQPLAIN.

Comment: Ну если у вас скрипт на одном сервере, а очередь на другом, то почему `localhost` ?

Comment: Это как пример, чтобы актуальные данные не палить
Главное строка подключения ведь и ошибка 
@rjhdby